# Wordpress upload file size error even after raising php limits

Tags: nginx, centos, php-fpm, wordpress, digital-ocean

I get 'The uploaded file exceeds the uploadmaxfilesize directive in php.ini.' error while trying to upload a plugin which is just 5.1MB.
I have raised the limits in php.ini file and also thru webmin.

This is my php.ini file

```
max_input_time = 24000
max_execution_time = 24000
upload_max_filesize = 12000M
post_max_size = 24000M
memory_limit = 12000M
```

Here is my nginx.conf file. I have also increased clientmaxbody_size under server and http.

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
client_max_body_size 24000M;
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
.........
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
server {
    client_max_body_size 24000M;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
 .....
```

Comment: Those settings look sufficient. Make sure you've actually restarted php-fpm with those settings.

Comment: I restarted both nginx and php-fpm using the commands
systemctl restart php-fpm.service
sudo systemctl restart nginx
But I still get the same error!
Any help would be appericiated! Thanks